# Can't remove a binary search tree

Tags: c, sorting, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I have a C code which creates an AVL Tree. I've coded all of the functions to create a tree, but I stuck in the last step which is removing the tree. The function simply does not work. Here is my `tree_free` function;

```
void tree_free(TREE tree){
 
     if (tree != NULL){
        tree_free(tree->root->right);
        free(tree->root->data); 
        tree_free(tree->root->left);
        free(tree);
     }

}
```

**So for those who will want to see the insertion function and structs, I will share the codes of these function below.**

Here is how I insert numbers in my tree;

```
void avl_insert(TREE tree, unsigned long long data){


    tree->root = avl_insert_recursive(tree->root, data);

}
```

And here is the `avl_insert_recursive` function;

```
NODE avl_insert_recursive(NODE node, unsigned long long data){

    int balance = 0;


    if( node == NULL){
    
        return(node_init(data));
    }
    
    if( data < node->data ){
    
    
        node->left = avl_insert_recursive(node->left, data);
        return node;
    
    
    }else if( data > node->data){
    
        
        node->right = avl_insert_recursive(node->right, data);
        return node;

    
    }else{
    
        return node;
    }

    node->height = 1 + max(local_height(node->left), local_height(node->right));

    return node;
```

}

Lastly, I want to share with you the structs which I created for the **TREE** and **NODE** data types.

```
typedef struct NODE_s *NODE;
typedef struct NODE_s
{
    NODE right;
    NODE left;
    unsigned long long data;
    int height;
} NODE_t[1];

typedef struct TREE_s *TREE;
typedef struct TREE_s
{
    NODE root;
} TREE_t[1];
```

So Can you diagnose the problem? Thanks for the help.

Comment: What do you mean by "simply does not work"? Does it segfault? Appear to succeed but you think you have a memory leak?

Comment: There is no error, program is ending when tree_free() function starts to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `tree_free()` function, you have this: `free(tree->root->data);`. But `tree->root->data` is not a pointer to memory that you previously allocated. You compiler should have warned you about that.

Additionally, your `avl_insert_recursive()` function seems wrong. There is a code path that will never be reached: `height` will never be updated because of the if else block. Also, `node->data` never gets set.

I would also recommend changing the `avl_insert_recursive()` signature. Instead of accepting a pointer to an already allocated memory for a node, it should accept a pointer to the root node, and allocate and insert the node itself. This way, you could remove `free(tree->root->data);` from `tree_free()`.

Comment: Then how I should change the line `free(tree->root->data);` ? What exactly should I be freeing ?

Comment: I would have a function called `node_free()` and it would do this: `void node_free(NODE node) { node_free(node->left); node_free(node->right); free(node); }` and I would call it from `tree_free()` like: `node_free(tree->root);`

Comment: But node has to be malloced in `avl_insert_recursive`. Hope that sets you on the right path.

Comment: Well also, how can I fix the problem in `avl_insert_recursive()` ? You said, height will never be updates because of if else block. But I need if else block over there to determine whether insert the number left or right. What would you suggest ?

Comment: Remove the return from the else block and allocate the node in there instead.

Comment: Well, I still can't fix the problem about `tree_free()`. I created function `node_free()` like you said, and then called it from `tree_free()` but it still not works.     `void node_free(NODE node){
 
 
 node_free(node->left); 
 node_free(node->right); 
 free(node);
}`   and another function is like this `void tree_free(TREE tree){ node_free(tree->root); }`

Comment: If you get totally stuck you can always look up an implementation of AVL, like for example this: https://gist.github.com/tonious/1377768 But it's best to try to figure it out yourself.